# How to solve error when running library(ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I meet this problem every time when I make a plot by ggplot2. It gives these 2 kinds of messages. The plot just works when I run it 2nd or 3rd times. Is there any trick to solve this? Please help!!!

Error in grid

> .newpage() :    unable to open file
>   'C:/Users/HUYNHC~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKYIZjb/aa0031b1689a45348b36982c12235633.png'
>   for writing

Warning message:

> In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :   unable to
>   open file
>   'C:/Users/HUYNHC~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKYIZjb/a8270216f8df4da693d2443415f2225b.png'
>   for writing

Comment: Did you try https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/imguR/versions/0.1.5/topics/dev.off `dev.off()` ?

Comment: I ran into this once - closed RStudio, restarted with Run as Administrator and then it worked fine. Don't know the root cause though

Comment: thanks, @amrrs. it works when I try dev.off() but I have to do it every time when I want to make a plot. It's a bit uncomfortable. I want to know what is the root cause.

Comment: Thanks @VivekKalyanarangan. I am going to try it.

Comment: Take a look at this archived discussion and see if it helps. I would try reinstalling `ggplot2` and/or `R/RStudio`. Cheers and hope it helps! The archived discussion:  https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/245232167-Problem-with-Plots-window